# HTTP Client Cookie c#

Tags: c#, post, cookies, http-headers, httpclient

I'm trying to set cookies and get cookies from a general method.

I saw this example that works but I'm having troubles in changing my own code in a way that I can keep my general function.

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://google.com").Result;

Uri uri = new Uri("http://google.com");
IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>();
foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + ": " + cookie.Value);

Console.ReadLine();
```

My code:

```
public static HttpClient CreateClientASMtoken(string tokenVal)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(urlASM)
    };
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new Cookie("token", tokenVal));
    return httpClient;
}
```

The commented code is one of my trys to make this happen. The other general method that I use is this:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostASM(string path, object content)
{
    string tokenVal = "d2GpEA5r8pwLRcOPxgaygPooldz2OZ2HUZzZ0YDPAOYCIiH4u5";            
    using (var client = CreateClientASMtoken(tokenVal))
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
        var serializedContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var postResponse = await client.PostAsync(path, serializedContent);
        
        //string response = await postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return postResponse;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I've tried this too:

[image]

But it shows an error and the URL is ok and so is the token.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that solves the problem easily. Thanks for the ones who contributed.

```
public static async Task<string> GetASM(string path)
{
    string tokenVal = "d2GpEA5r8p...";
    Uri uriASM = new(urlASM);
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    using var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
    };

    using var client = new HttpClient(handler)
    {
        BaseAddress = uriASM,
    };

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    cookieContainer.Add(uriASM, new Cookie("token", tokenVal));
    var getResponse = await client.GetAsync(path);
    return await getResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To add a cookie change the row:

```
//httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new Cookie("token", tokenVal));
```

to:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Set-Cookie", "token=test; path=/");
```

If you dont want the path part just go ahead and remove it.

If you want to be able to read out cookies fron a HttpResponseMessage you need to handle the parsing by yourself.

Here is a way to get all the cookies:

```
HttpClient client = CreateClientASMtoken("");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost").Result;
IEnumerable<string> rawCookies = response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie");
```

Try it out and you will see them in the same format as when you set them. As mentioned you will need to parse them out for yourself or find a class to do this for you.

Comment: Hi @FSDaniel I've tried your suggestion but doesn't work and the request is ok because I've tested with the REST Easy app and it works I substitute for "httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie","token="+tokenVal);" and its a bad request (the server replies this if the cookie is wrong)